# How to rotate/reflect lines of Feynman diagram - TikZ-Feynman

Tags: luatex, tikz-feynman, feynman

I'm trying to make the following Feynman diagrams via the TikZ-Feynman package, but I can't skew / rotate the lines as I would like. For example, for the first one, I can't keep all the input terms on the left. I searched around but found no one in my situation.

[image]

Example for the first

```
\begin{equation}
    \feynmandiagram [small, horizontal=i3 to f1] {
        i2 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^+\)] f1 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e-\)] i1,
        i3 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] f1,
    };
\end{equation}
```

Comment: What is your complete MWE?

Comment: MWE stands for?

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Minimal working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `TikZ-Feynman` commands use the spring layout algorithm to place all the edges. Your diagrams require each vertex to be placed manually.

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[right=of a] (b);
        \vertex[below right=of a] (f1);
        \vertex[above right=of a] (f2);
        \diagram*{
            (a) -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] (b),
            (a) -- [fermion, edge label'=\(e^-\)] (f1),
            (a) -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^+\)] (f2),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[right=of a] (b);
        \vertex[above left=of b] (f1);
        \vertex[above right=of b] (f2);
        \diagram*{
            (a) -- [photon, edge label'=\(\gamma\)] (b),
            (b) -- [anti fermion, edge label'=\(e^-\)] (f1),
            (b) -- [fermion, edge label'=\(e^-\)] (f2),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[right=of a] (b);
        \vertex[below right=of b] (f1);
        \vertex[above right=of b] (f2);
        \diagram*{
            (a) -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] (b),
            (b) -- [anti fermion, edge label'=\(e^+\)] (f1),
            (b) -- [fermion, edge label'=\(e^-\)] (f2),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]